# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' with my code

Tags: angular

I am learning angular and I am facing the issue of InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'.

html code

```
<div *ngIf="id$ | async">
      ....
      </div>
```

ts code

```
 id$: any;
  uid: string;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((paramMap: ParamMap) => paramMap.get(UID_PARAM)),
      filter((uid: string) => !!uid),
      tap((uid) => {
        this.uid = uid;
      })).subscribe(() => {
        this.getData();
      });
  }
```

```
getData() {
     this.restAPI.getDetails(this.uid)
    .subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

Here ApiResponse is a model.

Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: What does this.getData() method doing is it returing Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `this.id$` is no observable - it is a Subscription. Async pipe expects an observable.
Try

```
this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map((paramMap: ParamMap) => paramMap.get(UID_PARAM)),
  filter((uid: string) => !!uid)
);

this.id$.subscribe(id => {
    this.uid = id;
    this.getData();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **`getData()`** method is not returning an **`Observable`** you cannot use **`async`** pipe. If it is not returning an **`Observable`** remove **`async`** pipe or else change your code as follows.

**TS**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((paramMap: ParamMap) => paramMap.get(UID_PARAM)),
      filter((uid: string) => !!uid),
      tap((uid) => {
        return this.uid = uid;
      }));

    if (this.id$) {
        this.getData();
    }  
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="id$ | async">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I understand it. Thanks!